# Some questions about google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Here is my code for a google map

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 900px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.979026,16.468506),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            name: 'Parking',
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          }
        };

        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        }

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
            type: 'Parking'
          }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)       
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Why is it wrong?
All what it is supposed to do is be centered and have a marker with the icon parking at a certain lat & long.
I tried following the google tutorial, but I understand it
So any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use MarkerImage to place an custom icon

```
img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('parking_lot_maps.png');
```

then

```
Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    icon: img,
});
```